# How to sort my app widgets when adding a new one?

Tags: android, widget, home-screen-widget

My app has several widgets. Each of them is declared in the Manifest file with something like this:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".MyWidgetProvider1"
        android:exported="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/MyIcon1"
        android:label="First widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/WidgetLayOut" />
    </receiver>
```

I have 5 of them. Right now when long-pressing on the home screen the System shows the different apps with widgets. When tapping on my app, then the System expands and shows a list with the 5 available widgets that my app has. Good so far.

The problem is the widgets are sorted by the name. Can I choose how they are displayed? I would like to change the order of the list.

Changing the order in the manifest file doesn't help.

Comment: Hi. The same issue, could you please tell whether you was able to solve this issue?

Comment: When you say the default is sorted by `name`, which id is that in the manifest?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: No. I removed the widgets from my app. I realized that what I really needed was Shortcuts.